# Editing attribute columns to switch properties from text to integer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, fields-attributes

Instead of adding an entire new column in my attributes table, is there a way I can edit the properties of an existing (unnecessary) column and change the type from integer to text?